# How to record a Payment by Check for an existing Participant

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, contributions

When participants register to an Event, they can choose the "pay later" option.

Then, they send a check to the Event manager.

How can he record this payment ?

For security reasons, I am not very fond of letting him use the standard UI ; is it possible to do this via a webform just containing :

- Contact1,
- Event,
- Amount,
- Check number,
- Date

... or an alternative to webform (e.g. Profile ?) ?

I am in Civi 4.7.16 / Drupal 7.54

Comment: It may be best to have a go at such a webform and confirm yourself. But you may get lucky and find someone who has done exact same. I haven't seen mention of it though. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Pete for your quick answer; I am not sure I understand clearly what you mean : I don't know how to make such a webform (containing check payment info)

Comment: when you said 'webform' i assumed you meant a webform_civicrm type form. now i am not so sure. have you tried to set up a webform, configure it for using civicrm, set up Event tab, and a contribution page set on the contribution tab? if this is your first go at making a webform_civicrm then better you start on the webform_civicrm documentation. I may be able to fire you a screenshot if it helps

Comment: Thank you again Pete for your quick answer. But I do all this (I mean and am used to Webform_civicrm, which I use a lot and am very fond of). But the Contribution Page only proposes "Pay later" or "Pay now on line", but not "record payment by check" (I would love it).

Comment: sounds like it would require some development of the webform_civicrm module then to allow this. sorry I hadn't looked at civicrm/contribution tab on webform for a while. best to ask on drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm but no idea if it will get done without contribution of code/funds.

Comment: @Jacques-MarieMoranne was there any progress on this topic? I've hit the same request.

Comment: @Aidan : Yes : I subcontracted fuzion (petednz) to develop a parameterized search which works like a Smart Group, then enables multiple updates on participants (or members, or contributors). It should be integrated in CiviCRM core (not yet in 5.6.0, and I did not test 5.6.1). I would be glad to send you some documentation (in french, but easy to understand), but I don't know how to do that.